# How can I extract a url from a string, which contains a space between the protocol and the rest of the address?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose, I have the following string (in Python):

```
myString = "For further information please visit http:// somewebpage.com and please do not hesitate to contact us"
```

I'd like to extract the following url:

```
http:// somewebpage.com
```

I found solutions using regex but not for the case of a blank before the address.

Comment: which protocols are you expecting ?

Comment: @marvel308 only http

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
myString = myString.split()
index = myString.index('http://')
url = ''.join(myString[index:index+2])
```

Notice i'm splitting the sentence on every word but only connecting the `http` part with the one immediately after that.

If you actually need the space (I can't imagine why) then replace `''` with `' '`

Comment: This one gets http://somewebpage.com instead of 'http:// somewebpage.com'.

Comment: Excuse me, it is a problem with the formatting of Stack Overflow. I would like to mean that there is no space between 'http://' and the remaining string of the url.

Comment: Nice I think that the solution is now OK.

Comment: @ Ofer Sadan Thank you very much. It's weird, I use a scraper for old tweets and embedded urls always have a space after the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Pure regex solution:

```
http://\s[\w\.]+
```

- `[\w\.]` looks for any letter or period
- `+` looks for the above characters 1 or more times

Comment: @ LukeBalizet Thank you. This one works well. Replacing the space of the regex-output provides me with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex :

```
>>>mystring = "For further information please visit http:// somewebpage.com and please do not hesitate to contact us"

>>>url = re.findall('http[s]?:// (?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', mystring)[0]
>>>url
http:// somewebpage.com
```

Comment: Try for what? What are we looking for here?

Comment: @rick112358 the regex returns the url from the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
/https?:\/\/\s\S+/g
```

- **http** - Matches http sequence
- **s?** - Matches 0 or 1 s (for http**s**)
- **:** - Matches :
- **//** - Matches two //
- **\s** - Matches one space
- **\S+** - Matches any character that is not a space 1 or more times

The regex will match:

```
http:// somewebpage.com
https:// somewebpage.com
http:// 1234.com/test
```

But not:

```
ftp:// www.test.com.xx
http://www.google.com
http://
```

http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=98273